# iTunes library update

Tags: itunes, library

I have a new pc and just re-downloaded iTunes. When I tried syncing, the iTunes Library would not update from my iPad Library! instead it tries to replace the iPad library with just the few songs I bought online, which are in iCloud. But I have several old songs I burnt from CDs. Please how do i update the iTunes library with my iPad library?

Answer (score 1):

The library never will sync from different computers, it's a way to protect the author right's and the unique thing that this will do is show your songs that you buy with iCloud.

The unique solution is going to your other computer and copy the song in the folder iTunes>Music and put on the new!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One of two ways...

[Copy the data from the old computer to the new](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527)
or [Lift the data off the iPhone directly](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3991) - which requires 3rd Party software.